# Silly question: Why is it in the diagonalization process we can choose our eigenvector to be anything we want?

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, diagonalization

Suppose we want to diagonalize the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}0& 1\\  -1& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Then using $det(\lambda I - A) = 0$

We find our eigenvalues to be $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm j$

Solving for the $\lambda_1 = j$ eigenvector, we find that

$V_{1} = [V_{11}, V_{12}] = [V_{11}, jV_{11}]$, where $V_1$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$

Now my professor simply equates 1 to be $V_{11}$ to get $V_1 = [1, j]$

WHAT? But why!? Can someone explain what is the logical mental process that says you can so freely choose $V_{11}$ to be 1?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is a linear operation so if $Ax = \lambda x$ then $A(x+x) = \lambda(x+x)$ and in general $A(cx) = \lambda(cx)$ for any constant $c$. This mean that is $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ then so is also $cx$ for any constant $c$. This means that we have the freedom to fix $V_{11}$ (or $V_{12}$) to be whatever non-zero value we want. For simplicity $1$ is the obvious choice.

Comment: @Winter Okay I missed the for simplicity part in class then. This should be a fundamental theorem of linear algebra "first value in the eigenvector should be 1 for simplicity sake".

Comment: @MathNewb To be exact this is not always true. For example, what if the first entry of the eigenvalue is $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many eigenvectors corresponding to one eigenvalue, just check:
If $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of a matrix $A$, then isn't $\mu x$ also an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$?

Comment: What is the physical interpretation of your statement?

Comment: $Ax=\lambda x$ then of course $A(\mu x)=\lambda (\mu x)$. An eigenvector $x$ multiplied by $A$ will be transformed (or projected) into another vector $\lambda x$. If $\lambda$ is real, the two vectors are aligned, if complex, there will be a specific angle between the two, just like complex multiplication does.

Comment: @MathNewb For example, let's say $\lambda=(a+bj)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{j\arctan(\frac ba)}$, which means $\lambda x$ will be rotating $x$ by $\arctan(\frac ba)$ (anticlockwise) and then stretching it $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ times.